# Python win32com.client and dynamic.py syntax error

Tags: python, win32com

I am experiencing a strange error on my team with a Python script we're using. User A was having issues with their computer and required re-imaging. They logged into User B's machine to perform some work in the interim. After using User B's computer, User B is now having the following error when running our python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\script.py", line 10, in <module>
    import win32com.client as win32
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init.py__", line 10, in <module>
    from . import dynamic
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 557
    try.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The user has reinstalled python and pip installed the necessary packages for our environment and is still running into the issue. The lines in dynamic.py of win32com relative to this are:

```
 557    if attr in self._olerepr_.propMapPut:
 558         entry = self._olerepr_.propMapPut[attr]
 559         invoke_type = _GetDescInvokeType(entry, pythoncom.INVOKE_PROPERTYPUT)
 560         self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
 561         return
```

I cannot determine what differences in the roaming profiles caused the primary user's python files to read entry.dispid as invalid syntax, especially after re-installing the files.

Comment: Have you tried shoving the file through `od` yet?

Comment: That looks like maybe it's reading line 560 as starting with `try.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)` and since `try` is a keyword and needs a space after it, the syntax error is happening there. Is that part of `dynamic.py` on User B's computer missing the start of the line? (Could be that User A accidentally deleted some characters and didn't notice.)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I am not familiar with that. Elaborate?

Comment: @bouteillebleu - From User B's dynamic.py: `560       self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)`